# Does "git svn rebase" damage a non-"git svn" repository?

Tags: git, svn, rebase

By mistake I did the command `git svn rebase` in a "normal" git repository, that is, one that was not created using `git svn clone`.

Unsurprisingly, I got some errors in the output:

```
> git svn rebase
Migrating from a git-svn v1 layout...
Data from a previous version of git-svn exists, but
        .git/svn
        (required for this version (2.6.1.windows.1) of git-svn) does not exist.
Done migrating from a git-svn v1 layout
foo/bar.ts: needs update
foo/common-sass.scss: needs update
[... more files needing update ...]
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
```

I haven't noticed any further error, but I'm still worried: Did this do any lasting damage to my repo? Any corruption of configuration?

I could of course erase my old repo and clone a new one. But do I have to?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There might be extra records at `.git/config` but otherwise should be just fine.